# How to add/import contact details via QR code in ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, contacts, bq

my steps :

Select contacts> new contact> click on + button (which looks like empty contact image) > select tagger app > only option shown is "insert code content" It is not possible to paste previously copied information there.

Expected behaviour is to scan QR code.

the other way around=scanning QR code with Vcard in tagger first does not offer "save in contacts option.

Ubuntu touch 14.10(r22)on BQ 4.5, Thank you

Comment: That is not possible as of now. Please file a bug.